# HikariCP Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hikariConfig' while setting constructor argument

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, hikaricp

I am trying to switch from c3p0 to HikariCP after hearing great reviews from many people. I am stuck with one error. I couldn't figure out what exactly i am doing wrong.
Tech used: Spring 4, Hibernate 4.3.7, HikariCP 2.4.1, Oracle 11g and hibernate-hikaricp:5.0.2.Final

Spring configuration file: config.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig" />
</bean>
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <property name="poolName" value="springHikariCP" />
    <property name="connectionTestQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
    <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" />
    <property name="dataSourceProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip-address:1521:xe</prop>
            <prop key="user">{username}</prop>
            <prop key="password">{password}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="hibernate4SessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
 ......
```

java file:AccountsController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/web/validate", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> webRequestValidate(@RequestBody String jsonData) throws AccountNotFoundException {

    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml");
    try {
        UsersDAO usersDAO = context.getBean(UsersDAO.class);
                     String result = usersDAO.validate(jsonData);
                    ....
```

Error message:

```
2015-10-01 19:23:51 INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader:317 - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [config.xml]
2015-10-01 19:23:51 WARN  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext:487 - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hikariConfig' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hikariConfig' defined in class path resource [config.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at                 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:648)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1131)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1034)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at com.improvonia.app.api.AccountsController.webRequestValidate(AccountsController.java:126)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:438)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:179)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
```

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Never NEVER NEVER create an application context because you need a bean, that is what dependency injection is for. Inject the `UserDAO` don't create an `ApplicationContext` and retrieve it. Unless you want to have memory issues, performance issues, strange database concurrency issues etc.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum thanks for the reply. Could you please give me an example or point me to url where i can see how to implement that

Comment: I guess what he means is `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml"); UsersDAO usersDAO = context.getBean(UsersDAO.class);` You should just @Autowire a UsersDAO object instead retrieving it through context.